# mongoDB is taking too much space on disk

Tags: mongodb, diskspace, database

I inserted 1.500.000 documents with following body:

```
{
"_id" : 712613,
"cn" : " Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. ",
"d" : 1378396279,
"s" : 1,
"c" : 1,
"tc" : 0,
"tl" : 0,
"ts" : 0,
"ua" : "",
"ub" : "",
"i" : "",
"ip" : "this is image",
"cr" : "946666,1946914,784176,127189,55197,1014487,665449,1016059,1746099,818935",
"tg" : ""
}
```

as you see, I've shortened names to reduce document size, it's about 820 characters.
with 1.5 million documents , used disk space is 3GB.

WHy mongoDB takes so much space?

Comment: is there a text index somewhere? dictionaries can be huge.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB preallocates data files aggressively in order to avoid delays later, when it needs a new file.

Link: [Why are the files in my data directory larger than data in my database?](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#why-are-the-files-in-my-data-directory-larger-than-the-data-in-my-database)

Comment: so it seems there is no way to get rid of those huge files?

Comment: There is. Read about --noprealloc and --smallfiles options